# ¿Cómo se dice 'elevator pitch' en español?

Tags: traducción

¿Hay algún termino en contextos de negocios en español para referirse al término inglés **"elevator pitch"**?

Comment: Recomendado: [elevator pitch, alternativas en español, de Fundéu](https://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/elevator-pitch-alternativas-en-espanol/)

Comment: Sugiero adicionar un texto o referencia donde se use esa expresión.

Comment: pitch en todo caso es "argumento de venta" o argumentario de venta, Diría yo: argumentario rápido

Answer (score 5):

Pues no conocía el término y parece que se las trae en español. He encontrado tres conversaciones en el foro de wordreference y la página de la wikipedia en español (que ni lo traduce):

- http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=268841
- http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2425265
- http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2683748

Lo que me haría suponer que realmente no existe una traducción, a día de hoy, suficientemente uniforme, si no fuese porque en google hay casi 60 000 referencias a "discurso del ascensor", es más, hasta algunas universidades lo usan (Universidad de Cádiz: "Discurso del ascensor": http://www.uca.es/emprendedores/portal.do?TR=C&IDR=78).

Answer (score 5):

Lo lindo de estos dilemas es que nos da la opción de inventar algo nuevo. Las ideas anteriores son buenas y creo que hay como combinar. Sugiero como opción "propuesta en breve". Incluyo la preposición porque enfatiza una diferencia de una propuesta breve porque estoy de acuerdo con Diego de que "propuesta" suena a algo más amplio. "propuesta al paso" podría ser otro buen invento. ¿Qué piensan?

Comment: Te doy la bienvenida al sitio, user24580.  ¡Buen comienzo!

Answer (score 4):

"Elevator pitch" is strictly an Americanism. It is not used in most forms of English.

To parse it, I "translate" it into the English (slang) word "quickie," or the more polite "quick speech." The Spanish translation of this is **discurso breve**.

Comment: In England a 'quickie' is a 'rapidin'

Comment: @AdamBrown: What is a "rapidin." Does it have "social" connotations?

Comment: @TomAu a 'rapidin' is a short sexual encounter generally ad-hoc and not necessarily in a bed. If you say 'quickie' in england is has this connotation. 
http://mujeres.publimetro.com.mx/lugares-ideales-para-un-rapid-n

Comment: @AdamBrown: "Quickie" has the same connotations in American English. I was using the term "metaphorically" (although an elevator is a place to have one of the original). It was a bad (and unintended) pun that  I referred to as "slang" but served as a stepping stone to the translation.

Comment: Honestly, "rapidín" is used only in some contexts, you can not use that for a speech. It should be "discurso breve" or "discurso corto", both are valid from my pov. The use of "rapidin", is more like this. Mom-> "Recoge tu habitación", Son->"Vale mamá", Mom->"Rapidín eh!". You can use with friends, when you want something fast, it is pretty common to say "rapidín, rapidín", For example: "Necesito el documento de la reunión de ayer", "Vale ahora te lo envío por correo rapidín, rapidín", "Gracias".

Answer (score 3):

La traducción podria centrarse más en la búsqueda de convencimiento y buena impresión que el `elevator pitch` conlleva, lo cual está mejor expresado con una

> [ presentación / ] **persuasión relámpago**

Answer (score 1):

Medio tarde respondo, pero elevator pitch sería algo así como propuesta de ascensor (o como se diga ascensor/elevador en tu país). Es una breve sinópsis para venderle una idea a alguien. Es de ascensor, porque tiene que ser breve, se tiene que poder decir en lo que dura un viaje en ascensor/elevador.

Comment: Gracias Krinnen por la explicación de qué es el _elevator pitch_, pero fíjate que lo que se consulta es cómo mencionar este concepto en castellano. ¿Te atreves? Dale a [edit] para editar la respuesta con tu propuesta.

Comment: Entiendo que tu respuesta es "propuesta de ascensor"? Creo que "propuesta" tiene un sentido mucha más amplio del que se recoge con "elevator pitch".

Answer (score 0):

"Give me your elevator pitch":

> A ver, échame tu rollito.  Dime, ¿por qué debo apoyar tu propuesta?

*After drafting the above, I checked linguee.com and found that mostly, people had copped out and put "elevator-pitch" into their Spanish sentence, without translating it.  Some used a literal translation such as "resume de acensor."  The one that took the cake: "tono del ascensor."  (Tono = pitch -- how high or low the sound is!)*

Answer (score 0):

“Propuesta” denota la búsqueda de un acuerdo.  En cambio, “a pitch” busca una venta o transacción.  Esto me lleva a proponer “un comercial” como una opción más cercana: "**Comercial de Ascensor**".

Comment: pitch es un argumento de venta o valor